What genres should I explore next?
I’ve been wondering lately, what genres should I dive into next with my writing? I feel like I’m stuck in a bit of a rut, always writing the same kind of stuff. I want to switch things up and try something new that’ll challenge me.
Maybe I should give poetry a shot, even though I’m not exactly a master at it. Or I could go wild with sci-fi or fantasy—create some weird worlds and characters. Nonfiction could be cool too, like writing personal essays or even a memoir. I don’t know, something raw and real.
But then again, what if I try mystery? I’ve always been intrigued by how those stories unfold, but it feels a little intimidating. Honestly, I’m not sure what direction to go in yet. Should I stick to what I enjoy reading, or go out of my comfort zone and try something totally different? I guess whatever I choose, it’ll teach me something new about my writing.

Why do you write?
I write because I have a pressing need to explore my inner reality. What I write is dictated by the landscape of my mind. I cannot just write something that isn't within myself.
From what I have observed, most writers who write because it is something they must do, regardless of financial or popular success, have a similar "vision". They write what is inside of them. Or: They write who they are.
I have always known what I wanted to write. There was never any doubt about the type of story that I needed to tell and the way I had to tell it. And whenever I tried to write something else, for example as a commission, writing lost all appeal to me and ultimately felt like any other day job that I didn't care about. If I write something that I don't need to write, I might as well bake bread, build roads, or trade at the stock market – it all feels the same.
So the question you need to figure out an answer to is, what does writing mean to you and what purpose does it serve in your life? Is it a way to make money? Then it doesn't matter what you write and you can choose any genre that is currently popular and promises high revenues. Or is it a compassion? Then you need to become aware of and follow your fears and desires. They will guide you and tell you what you need to write.

The danger in writing in a genre because you rationalize that it might be advantageous to your skill to try your hand at it is that what you write might turn out shallow and generic. Your writing will only be fresh and intriguing if you have some kind of personal relationship to your story. Your emotions will make it, as you call it, "raw and real".
That doesn't mean that you have to decide on and limit yourself to a single genre. I write in different genres and for different audiences, because different genres interest me. But I always follow my "need-to-write". In any genre, the story is always my own and one that had been growing in me for some time.
The question for me isn't what genre I want to write in, but which of the many story ideas that accumulate in my mind over time I keep turning over in my head the most and which of these begin, under my continued consideration, to slowly develop a personal meaning and unfold into something that I feel strongly about. It is a process, not a decision.
